# Caching query results vs Querying each time (finding a middle ground)

Tags: performance, sql-server, caching

This is kind of an expansion on [a previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793746/cache-results-from-sql-database-or-query-each-time)

Some background info:

> Querying Over 5,000 items from SQL database that eventually get sorted
> into a list depending on who the user is.  One problem is that users
> are allowed to have customized lists which means that filtering these
> 5,000+ items in a uniform way is probably impossible.
>
> Also, important that the amount of users (and users wanting to have
> custom item lists) is constantly growing, so there will be an
> unprecedented amount of ways to sort. Basically, we won't be paying
> attention to filtering this growing list.
>
> Two methods we've come up with so far:
> -Option 1: Cache item list PER USER (and filter the items needed after) OR
> -Option 2: Cache the list once for the whole site (every user accesses this one cached list)
>
> The issue with Option 1 is that there will be duplicated lists in
> cache. Although we do not have an amount of users that will strain our
> server's memory, we obviously want our system to have scalability.
>
> The issue with Option 2 is that there will be duplicated items in the
> single, cached list. With the amount of users we have, this can
> quickly turn into a disorganized list full of duplicated items (i.e.
> 5,000 items can quickly turn into 10,000 based on a few user's custom
> item preferences)

Is there a "middle ground" for dealing with this situation? One that combines some benefits of querying and caching.

Even if a response is a link to a potentially helpful source, I would appreciate it as I am kind of at a fork in the road.

Looking to open up new possible paths in my brainstorming.

Comment: `sorting these 5,000+ items in a uniform way is probably impossible.` -- Why?

Comment: @RobertHarvey because there isn't a uniform way to sort them. Basically, if a user (customer) needs a custom item list, we give it to them. Unfortunately, we have to work around this "company flexibility".

Comment: There are display grids that do this all the time.  Excel can do this.  What do you mean by "uniform?"

Comment: 10,000 items in a list isn't that big anymore.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The point I am making is that this list is constantly growing, and the amount of users that want customized item lists is constantly growing.

Comment: That's not a problem until it is, is it?  How big are these lists expected to grow?  50,000?  500,000? 5 million?  How many users want a customized list?  All of them?  By the time the list grows that large, it's going to be too large for the user to manage anyway, and I can't imagine any scenario where you can't provide the users some form of "saved searches and sorts" that's essentially unlimited.

Comment: @DanPichelman you're right it isn't. This is about scalability. But if a thousand users want customized lists, how many duplicates will we end up having? This small list of 5,000 results can grow to much more.

Comment: Does it matter if they're duplicated?  The customized lists are *per user* anyway, right?  You could always provide some sort of public area for users to share their customized list definitions, or provide some pre-defined ones for the most common use cases.

Comment: hmm. I don't think I am getting my ideas across clearly and I apologize. Is it possible to answer what I am asking about a "middle ground" between caching and querying?

Comment: I have a feeling we may be looking at an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218240) problem.  What's the cost if you don't cache at all & just keep hitting the database?

Comment: @DanPichelman the cost if Network performance as the database we are hitting is the same one everybody in office uses. it's a proprietary database, so there is a user limit (which isn't a problem now, but will become one)

Comment: By "sorting", do you also mean "filtering"?

Comment: @DanPichelman yes it is filtering. And I should probably edit my post for that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I apologize for any confusion regarding sorting. I meant filtering.

Comment: @DanPichelman I also want to add that we've considered implementing with caching per user. As we can just use user settings to filter the cached list. But we feel as though there must be a method we are missing or haven't brainstormed yet.

Comment: What is the specific problem that you're trying to solve?  Have you considered an AutoSuggest/AutoComplete text box to set a filter?

Comment: @RobertHarvey this is a performance issue involving scalability. I want to avoid solutions involving filtering. The main issue is that caching a single list could end up being large and disorganized. Caching a list per user could result in RAM limitations. Querying the database over and over is a network strain.

Comment: Autosuggest is a "divide and conquer" strategy.  The list of keywords or phrases that you send to the browser can be fairly large, and it's always the same list.  Once the user chooses something from the keywords list, the resulting display is small enough to be manageable.  Filtering is not a problem, it's a solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see what you're saying but users aren't choosing keywords to filter the results. The results they see will be based off their profile. If they need custom items, we assign it. Now I can picture a solution involving this type of filtering in server-side code, but how will that affect actual performance and speed? Will the number of users triggering these processes also affect the performance and speed?

Comment: There's no way to know that without measuring.  You can tune it later, but only if you have a reasonable way to limit the number of records first.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for all your help so far. Well I'll have to look into that but I don't see limiting the number of records as being a viable option. Maybe I just don't understand you properly and I apologize. One important point is that users are not allowed to see every item. There is no user-interface filtering, this is all done server-side. Again, the question was meant to focus on finding a middle ground between Querying over and over, or querying once and caching the total results. If you do not think this exists, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Some may not feel this is not an answer, but it is a way to derive a better answer.

**Collect data on user behavior.**
Many users may prefer a default configuration. If so, it would make sense to cache this list. I've seen some apps that are highly configurable, but I just use it the way it came out of the box. I'm sure there are hundreds of settings for Microsoft Word that 90% of users never bother using.

Otherwise, pull it from the database/disk. Depending on the size of the db and your particular RDBMS, most of your data may be in memory anyway (I know SQL Server does this.). This is where you'll start seeing any bottlenecks. You can address those later.

Don't be too anxious to solve a problem too soon. It may not be a problem. The wrong problem or the wrong solution. As much as you may want some sort of "best practice" or standard use case, there probably isn't one that matches your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should cache the query by the query parameters. In this case user id.

However, the point of caching is to prevent running the same query multiple times in quick sucession.

This would usualy be caused by each user running the same query per request. When you have 1000 users on the site and each making requests at the same time and running a getMenu query for example, wont all hit the database and overload your db. The first one runs and  the rest get the cached result. Your Db has to run a query per second instead of 1000 queries per second.

Assuming your code is reasonably well written though, you wouldnt expect a single request to make the same call lots of times, or a single user to make many multiple requests for the same thing. As each user is making a unique query they will all hit the db. They dont benefit from a differnt user already having made the call. If you cache al the results, you dont really see much benefit and will run out of memory.

so caching is unlikely to help you much.

I think the comments hit the nail on the head that your custom per user list is inherrently unscaleable.

Maybe you can divide it into a standard list and per user modifications? or opt in groups of items?

OR

you can cache the list client side. ie a cookie. this allows your effective memory to scale with your users.